# JavaScript generated div tags appearing behind other elements - with z-index set

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I'm trying to create and make a new div tag appear in response to a setInterval called function call. The div tag does appear - it exists when I check chrome developer tools, but it doesn't appear on top of the other elements that are in place.

I've set the z-index of the newly generated div to 2000, no other z-index is larger. After the code runs, I can see the newly created div tags using Chrome Dev Tools, but they are behind the other divs. They should appear in front of everything else.

**CSS**

```
#main_wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width:850px;
  border:solid 4px #ccc;
  overflow: visible;
  display: table;
}
#my_img{
  position: relative;
  width:650px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#hgh_lghtr{
  position: absolute;
  top:5px;
  left:1px;
  z-index:1000;
  border:solid 4px green;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
#cntnt_bx{
  position: relative;
  top:0px;
  z-index:22;
  border:solid 4px red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 14px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#mini_nav_hd{
  position:relative;
  top:0px;
  z-index:33;
  width:92%;
  margin:0 auto;
  min-height:20px;
  border: solid 2px green;
}

#tmp_bx{
  position: absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:50px;
  z-index:2000;
  border:solid 4px green;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
  var slides = [
    {  "name":"slide1",
       "x":5,
       "y":1,
       "width": 20,
       "height": 20,
       "color":"#D80000",
       "title":"Navigation Toggle",
       "desc":"Shows hides the nagivation menu."
     }
  ];

  //***********************************************************
  //Changes location of pre-existing div and attempts to create
  //new div and append it
  //***********************************************************
  function changHlghtrPos(){
    var slide = slides[slideCntr];

    document.getElementById("hgh_lghtr").style.borderColor = "red";
    document.getElementById("hgh_lghtr").style.top = slide.y + "px";
    document.getElementById("hgh_lghtr").style.left = slide.x + "px";
    document.getElementById("hgh_lghtr").style.width = slide.width + "px";
    document.getElementById("hgh_lghtr").style.height = slide.height + "px";

    var tmp_bx = document.createElement("div");
    tmp_bx.id = "tmp_bx";
    document.getElementById("main_wrapper").appendChild(tmp_bx);
  }

  slideCntr = 0;

  //******************************************
  //Determines if it is ok to move the pre-existing div
  //to the next location or clearInterval
  //******************************************
  function nextSpot(){
    if(slideCntr < 5){
      slideCntr += 1;
      changHlghtrPos();
    }else{
      clearInterval(nTime);
    }
  }


  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main_wrapper").empty();
    var main_hldr = document.getElementById("main_wrapper");

    var my_img = document.createElement("img");
    my_img.id = "my_img";
    my_img.src = "https://some_image.png";
    my_img.alt = "MyProject";

    var cntnt_bx = document.createElement("div");
    cntnt_bx.id = "cntnt_bx";

    var hgh_lghtr = document.createElement("div");
    hgh_lghtr.id = "hgh_lghtr";

    main_hldr.appendChild(my_img);
    main_hldr.appendChild(hgh_lghtr);
    main_hldr.appendChild(cntnt_bx);

    var mini_nav_hd = document.createElement("div");
    mini_nav_hd.id = "mini_nav_hd";
    mini_nav_hd.textContent = "Navigation";

    var cntntBx = document.getElementById("cntnt_bx");
    cntntBx.appendChild(mini_nav_hd);

    nTime = setInterval(nextSpot,2000);

  });
</script>
```

Sample HTML

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div id="main_wrapper">
      <!--three elements are generated when page loads-->
      <!--one element is generated in response to setInterval-->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: IDs have to be unique – by calling your function `changHlghtrPos` multiple times, you are inserting multiple elements with the same ID. (Btw., why the curde mixture of jQuery and “vanilla” JavaScript …?)

Comment: Thanks, I caught the multiple IDs and changed it to class. No particular reason for mixing, sometimes if I think it is easier in jQuery I will use it, and there are many places in here where I could replace with jQuery, but I want to keep up on my vanilla JavaScript skills also.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/k4htrrqw/) you want? If it works,

```
function nextSpot(){
  if(slideCntr < 5){
    slideCntr += 1;
    changHlghtrPos();
  }else{
    clearInterval(nTime);
  }
}
```

Maybe you need to switch the place of `slideCntr += 1;` with the place of `changHlghtrPos();`, because index of array starts with 0.

Comment: I've tried it both ways and this part still functions as it should. I declared an array and set slideCntr = 0 initially - and as you see, I"m testing the value of slideCntr before I increment it.